# Intellij content assist java doc

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I changed my IDE from Eclipse to Intellij. I like Intellij, it's more helpful, but I miss a feature from Eclipse. When I was writing in Eclipse a function, like "text".is the IDE showed me a list of function I could use and when I select one of those it shows the java doc of that function like in this picture:
[image: eclipse]

I want this in Intellij too, but I don't know how.
Ctrl+Q should give me that,but it isn't. It shows me only the package and the atent of function:
For "text".isEmpty() it gives me:

```
java.lang.String
public boolean isEmpty()
```

Comment: Check if the SDK configuration has some entries in the "documentation paths" tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you're missing javadocs/sources of the related library. In order to display popup with help, you need one of it. They can be attached related library "part" of the window under File -> Project structure dialog:
[image]

Here is the screenshot of how it looks:
[image]